# How to deal with stale pooled connections in Java

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, connection-pooling

I have this Pooled data source I use in my Java app:

```
public class PointsDataSource {
    public static javax.sql.DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI, String username, String password) {
        //
        // First, we'll create a ConnectionFactory that the
        // pool will use to create Connections.
        // We'll use the DriverManagerConnectionFactory,
        // using the connect string passed in the command line
        // arguments.
        //
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI,username, password);
        //
        // Next we'll create the PoolableConnectionFactory, which wraps
        // the "real" Connections created by the ConnectionFactory with
        // the classes that implement the pooling functionality.
        //
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory =
                new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
        //
        // Now we'll need an ObjectPool that serves as the
        // actual pool of connections.
        //
        // We'll use a GenericObjectPool instance, although
        // any ObjectPool implementation will suffice.
        //
        ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool =
                new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory);

        // Set the factory's pool property to the owning pool
        poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);

        //
        // Finally, we create the PoolingDriver itself,
        // passing in the object pool we created.
        //
        PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource =
                new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And then I just call `ds.getConnection()` whenever I need one.

The problem is - time to time connections become stale, and I get a CommunicationError exception when using such connection, though the consequent calls succeed.

What is the right way of reopening the connections I got from the pooled datasource before using them to avoid this error?

I could make a test call like `SELECT current_date()` and silence a possible exception before making real calls to the database but is there a better way?

Comment: Test call is the usual technique, typically `SELECT 1`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne so I make that call in try-catch and silence a possible exception, and then proceed with the intended call, correct?

Comment: @Andrey -- I think this is the most common approach, although there are other possibilities. But why implement the connection pool yourself, when there are so many solid open-source implementations already? Connection pooling is surprisingly difficult to do in a robust way.

Comment: @KevinBoone I'm not a Java dev really, I just got a small project that I needed to implement in Java so I might have chosen a longer path. Could you point me to an existing open source implementation? I thought that the one I have above is already using open source apache pool libs - are you saying there are simpler implementations?

Comment: @Andry -- I must have misunderstood the original question. Sorry. But if you're using DBCP2, can you just call `setValidationQuery()` on the `PoolableConnectionFactory` ?